# Will Ubuntu touch have this transparency effect?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I saw the following stunning images of Ubuntu touch and wonder whether the glass blur effect is to be implemented. So, is there chance to see this really in Ubuntu touch 1.0?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't normally post on concept art but this looks fantastic I think Ubuntu apps should have a theming options where youcan choose the ccolour scheme.

Side note dunno why it doesn't look this nice on sailfish OS didn't think I'd like this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment).